# How to pass per-instance data (such as positioning) to shader in OpenGL 3.2 with instanced rendering?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to render cubes using instanced rendering. I got this to work and I render with glDrawArraysInstanced.

However, I now want to pass per-instance data (in this case positioning and colours) to the shader, and I have understood that I am meant to use the function glVertexAttribDivisor to achieve this. The problem is that that function is only available in OpenGL 3.3 and up and I am using 3.2

How can I achieve this in the Right Way in OpenGL 3.2?

Comment: I don't know about the "right way", but prior to GL 3.3, there was [`gl_InstanceID`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/gl_InstanceID.xhtml) in the vertex shader and you could use that as an index into an array backed by a uniform buffer object.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Yes that's a possible approach, but afaik uniform arrays are static size only, so if I have many objects of varying amounts then it wouldn't work. Or did I miss something?

Comment: It does limit the number of instances you can draw, yes. You will hit storage limitations no matter what solution you use. Alternatively you could use a buffer texture - they allow you to store more data than a UBO and the size doesn't have to be declared ahead of time.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Hmm true, but I guess it just seems weird to me to have a hardcoded limit. With the GL 3.3 vertex attribute method, there doesn't seem to be any such hardcoded limits and you just send exactly how much you need.

Comment: Which OpenGL implementation do you have that provides 3.2 and NOT 3.3?

Comment: @peppe: Lots of implementations like that exist, especially from Apple. But in the case of Apple at least, their 3.2 implementation includes the ARB extension for instanced arrays.

Comment: Oh, right, I always forget that Apple lives in 2010 :)

Comment: and using a sampler with which you use instanceID to index into a texture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find a nice way in 3.2 to do what I wanted so I updated to OpenGL 3.3 instead to be able to use [glVertexAttribDivisor](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribDivisor.xhtml) to send instance data in attributes.

Comment: That will do just fine. If you have a lot of instances there are almost always ways to reduce the size with some creativity.

Answer (score 2):

Optional solution :

Render points and emit a cube using a geometry shader. Then you can pack everything into one VBO and avoid instanced rendering.

Use transform feedback to modify cube properties if needed.